# CMake build system

Tags: c++, performance, object-oriented, cmake

I wasn't quite sure where to go with this, and this seemed to be the best place I could think of so I thought why not. I threw together a build system for C++ projects today using CMake and I wanted your opinions on it, on things I could do better, or change to better comply with best practices.

Here's my directory structure:

> ```
> .
> ├── bin (Compiled executables)
> │   └── lib (Executables from third-party libraries)
> ├── build (The CMake build folder)
> │   ├── CMakeCache.txt
> │   ├── CMakeFiles
> │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
> │   ├── inc
> │   ├── lib
> │   ├── Makefile
> │   └── test
> ├── CMakeLists.txt
> ├── inc (Objects used in programming)
> │   └── CMakeLists.txt
> |   └── fake_object (An example)
> |       └── fake_object.h
> |       └── fake_object.cc
> ├── lib (External/third-party libraries)
> │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
> │   └── gmock (Unit testing)
> ├── main.cc
> ├── res (External resources such as images, sounds, fonts)
> └── test (tests, lol)
>     └── CMakeLists.txt
> ```

I decided to take a modular approach to my C++ structure, so each object I build for my programs has its own directory within the inc folder.

Here is my main CMakeLists.txt:

```cpp
########################################################################
#                              Basic info                              #
########################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(skeleton)

########################################################################
#                              Variables                               #
########################################################################

# My vars
set(test_prefix ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test)
set(GMOCK_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/gmock)
set(GMOCK_TEST_LIBS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/lib)

# System vars
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -lpthread)

# Play around boiiiiiis
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(NO_MAIN true)
set(classes) # All objects go here

########################################################################
#                                 Main                                 #
########################################################################

##############
#  Includes  #
##############

include_directories(inc)
include_directories(res)

include_directories(${GMOCK_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${GMOCK_DIR}/gtest/include)

###########
#  Logic  #
###########

if(NOT ${NO_MAIN})
    add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.cc)
    target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${classes})
endif(NOT ${NO_MAIN})

########################################################################
#                         Where do we go now?                          #
########################################################################

add_subdirectory(inc)
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the test directory:

```cpp
########################################################################
#                         Find GMock/Test Libs                         #
########################################################################

find_library(GMOCK_LIBRARY
        NAMES gmock
        libgmock
        libgmock.a
        PATHS ${GMOCK_TEST_LIBS})

find_library(GMOCK_LIBRARY_MAIN
        NAMES gmock_main
        libgmock_main
        libgmock_main.a
        PATHS ${GMOCK_TEST_LIBS})

find_library(GTEST_LIBRARY
        NAMES gtest
        libgtest
        libgtest.a
        PATHS ${GMOCK_TEST_LIBS})

find_library(GTEST_LIBRARY_MAIN
        NAMES gtest_main
        libgtest_main
        libgtest.a
        PATHS ${GMOCK_TEST_LIBS})

########################################################################
#                            Compile tests                             #
########################################################################


#########################
#  Grab all test cases  #
#########################

set(test_sources)

foreach(TEST ${classes})
    list(APPEND test_sources "${TEST}_test.cc")
endforeach(TEST)

#######################
#  Create executable  #
#######################

if (DEFINED ${test_sources})
    add_executable(run_tests ${test_sources})

    target_link_libraries(run_tests ${GMOCK_LIBRARY} ${GMOCK_LIBRARY_MAIN})
    target_link_libraries(run_tests ${GTEST_LIBRARY} ${GTEST_LIBRARY_MAIN})
    target_link_libraries(run_tests ${classes})
endif(DEFINED ${test_sources})
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the inc directory:

```cpp
########################################################################
#                      Make all subdirs libraries                      #
########################################################################

foreach(INC ${classes})
    add_library(${INC} ${INC}/${INC}.cc)
endforeach(INC)
```

I'm also going to implement a doc directory for documentation (probably using Doxygen), but I've done so before and I know it's relatively easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

This generally looks pretty good, but I have a few suggestions that might allow you to make your code and build system a little better.

### Replace `inc` with `src`

The source code for your projects is apparently going into `inc`.  I would expect source code in `src` and header-only includes perhaps in `inc`.  I'd suggest changing from `inc` to `src` to make it clear that it's all source code and not just include files in there.

### Move your `main.cc` with the rest of the source code

There is no one place for source code with this system, which is unfortunate.  For something like `ctags` which can recursively build references to parts of your code, it's convenient for all of the code to be in a particular place, or at least at the top of a hierarchical directory tree.  This *might* be the top of a hierarchy, except that the `build` directory is also under it, so source files copied there would have to be explicitly excluded. For my projects, I find it easier to put the source in a single subdirectory named `src`.

### Reconsider "one directory per object"

If your projects are anything like mine, I think you'll find that there is very little to be gained in having each object get its own subdirectory.  I usually find it easier to put all of the source together in a single directory. Only major subsystems, rather than individual objects, get a subdirectory.

### Add a source package target

Sharing with others via source repository is good, but sometimes it's handy to just create a tarball.  For that, I'd recommend using CPack to create it.  Here's what I use:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "1")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "TBZ2")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME}_Source.tar.gz")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "/build/;/*.swp;.git*")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME
  "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
include (CPack)
```

One significant use of this is that once you have a "standard tree" set up, you can create the source tarball and then whenever you start a new project, simply untar the scaffolding into place and then go in and edit just the few things that would need to be project specific.

### Add a `doc` subdirectory

As you've mentioned, generating documentation via Doxygen is often handy.  I typically have a `doc` subdirectory off the top level into which the *source* for documentation would go.  That is, if `man` or user manual is generated, I put the sources in there.  I also tend to put programmer notes in there if they aren't already part of the Doxygen output.  Then the *generated* documents that result from all of that get put into the corresponding `doc` within the `build` tree.

### Add a top-level `README` file

I usually put in a `README` file at the very top.  One obvious thing to put into it would be exactly the directory tree structure that you put into your question, perhaps with a bit more explanation about what goes where and simple instructions for how to build the project.